# PHP class array error

Tags: php, arrays, class

I've written a class that looks at different parts of an email message. One function is to determine if each part is a file, by checking if a file name is present in its array of properties.

My check looks like:

```
if (array_key_exists("filename",$body_part->d_parameters)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

But I keep getting this error in my logs because in cases where the part is not a file (header, body etc.) there is no array key called "filename."

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$d_parameters in mail.php
PHP Warning:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in mail.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because `$body_part->d_parameters` doesn't exist when you reference it.

The second error is because `$body_part->d_parameters` isn't an array when you pass it to `array_key_exists()`

Solution: use `isset()` and `is_array()` before attempting to pass the object property into the function.

```
if ( isset($body_part->d_parameters) and is_array($body_part->d_parameters) and array_key_exists("filename",$body_part->d_parameters)) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I did add a bit more text a minute later, but maybe its because I answered a relatively basic PHP question?

Comment: No worries, I don't know too, I will upvote it though. However using `empty` you can write a conciser conditional statement: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7edb569af95a08d0ed71fcc3e26aa783fbbadf49

Comment: I had a derp moment with this. I decided to just go with `if isset($body_part->d_parameters[filename])`

Comment: That's fine too! I'll use `array_key_exists` if there's a chance of a `null` value too. Also you may want to use `isset($body_part->d_parameters['filename'])` (added quotes) Otherwise PHP is doing a constant to string translation with a warning/notice eg "*Notice: Use of undefined constant filename - assumed 'filename' in...*"